# Is it possible to use water heater drain valve as water source for a dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, dishwasher, installation

I want to install a dishwasher but there is no connection point on the pipes that I can use for water intake. The place where I want to install the dishwasher is not far from water heater, which led me to thinking: *is it safe and practical to use drain valve from water heater as a water source for a dishwasher?*

Additional details:

- There is a connection point on the wall for waste water disposal, so that's not a problem.
- The temperature of water in the water heater is 120 F, dishwasher can handle up to 160 F.

[image: Water heater diagram]

Another question that might be relevant and gives me hope that drain valve can actually be used:

[Why does my water heater's drain line rejoin the outlet pipe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131579/why-does-my-water-heaters-drain-line-rejoin-the-outlet-pipe?newreg=6b8796316d174fb793ab060aaf8c0dc9)

Comment: You may only get cold water out of the drain valve.  The cold water feed pipe may internally go to the bottom of the heater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless you want mostly cold or at best luke warm water.  Water heaters have something called a "dip tube" which is simply a tube(pipe) that delivers the cold water to the bottom of the tank. Also, you'll be introducing any sediment into the dishwasher, which could REALLY mess it up.

It shouldn't be at all hard to fit a T somewhere on the hot water outlet piping. Depending upon the exact connections, some are piped with flexible tubing in which case you'd just remove it, add 3 nipples on each side of a T and connect the DW.  I suggest brass rather than galvanized steel.  You may also want to add a valve to the DW in case you need to service or replace it someday.

Comment: But we would not need to remember to drain the sediment out of the hot water tank every so often.  Might be a bonus for some of us.

Comment: @crip659  Yeah?! But would you want that sediment going into a dishwasher? LOL

Comment: Many dishwashers heat the water if it is to cold. You might want to check yours.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is good. Unfortunately modification of piping is unreasonably hard (in my particular situation) so dishwasher is connected to drain valve now. Will update this comment or question when dishwasher is dead because of sediment, but at the moment dishes look perfectly clean, without any residual on them.